# Android linker: undefined reference to bsd_signal

Tags: android, android-ndk, static-libraries, build.gradle

I'm running `gradlew` to compile an Android app that has a static lib dependency. Somehow, I have an undefined reference to `bsd_signal`.

I was able to compile this app with gradle 1.X, but I've been obliged to switch to gradle 2.10 and to drop my `Android.mk` file in favour of putting more build instruction into my `gradle.build` file, and this is where the trouble arises.

Can anyone tell me whether there is a library that defines `bsd_signal`, which I should link to my project?

**Compiler output**

```
Starting process 'command '/home/myself/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++''. Working directory: /home/myself/projects/DroidEar/app Command: /home/myself/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ @/home/myself/projects/DroidEar/app/build/tmp/linkNativeArmeabi-v7aDebugSharedLibrary/options.txt
Successfully started process 'command '/home/myself/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++''
/android/ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/signal.h:113: error: undefined reference to 'bsd_signal'
/android/ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/signal.h:113: error: undefined reference to 'bsd_signal'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**TMI: Here is my gradle.build file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {            
            Superpowered {
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    def prefix = "src/main/jniLibs/Superpowered"
                    headers.srcDir "${prefix}"
                    if (targetPlatform.getName() == "armeabi-v7a")
                        staticLibraryFile = file("${prefix}/libSuperpoweredAndroidARM.a")
                    else if (targetPlatform.getName() == "arm64-v8a")
                        staticLibraryFile = file("${prefix}/libSuperpoweredAndroidARM64.a")
                    else if (targetPlatform.getName() == "x86_64")
                        staticLibraryFile = file("${prefix}/libSuperpoweredAndroidX86_64.a")
                    else if (targetPlatform.getName() == "X86")
                        staticLibraryFile = file("${prefix}/libSuperpoweredAndroidX86.a")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.3"

        sources {
            main {
                jni {
                    dependencies {
                        library "Superpowered" linkage "static"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ndk {
            ldLibs.addAll(['log', 'android', 'c'])
        }

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId = "edu.ucdavis.auditoryenhancer"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "native"
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

It looks to me like `bsd_signal` is defined in the `signal.o` component of `platforms/android-9/arch-x86/usr/lib/libc.a`, but even with my `ldLibs` call above including `c`, I get the error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Till **android-19** inclusive NDK-s `signal.h` declared `bsd_signal` *extern* and `signal` was an *inline* calling `bsd_signal`.

Starting with **android-21** `signal` is an *extern* and `bsd_signal` is not declared at all.

What's interesting, `bsd_signal` was still available as a symbol in **NDK r10e android-21** `libc.so` (so there were no linking errors if using **r10e**), but is not available in **NDK r11** and up.

Removing of `bsd_signal` from NDK-s **android-21+** `libc.so` results in linking errors if code built with **android-21+** is linked with static libs built with lower NDK levels that call `signal` or `bsd_signal`. Most popular library which calls `signal` is **OpenSSL**.

**WARNING**: Building those static libs with **android-21+** (which would put `signal` symbol directly) would link fine, but would result in `*.so` failing to load on older Android OS devices due to `signal` symbol not found in theirs `libc.so`.

Therefore it's better to stick with **<=android-19** for any code that calls `signal` or `bsd_signal`.

To link a library built with **<android-21** I ended up declaring a `bsd_signal` wrapper which would call `bsd_signal` from `libc.so` (it's still available in device's `libc.so`, even up to Android 7.0).

```
#if (__ANDROID_API__ > 19)
#include <android/api-level.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

extern "C" {
  typedef __sighandler_t (*bsd_signal_func_t)(int, __sighandler_t);
  bsd_signal_func_t bsd_signal_func = NULL;

  __sighandler_t bsd_signal(int s, __sighandler_t f) {
    if (bsd_signal_func == NULL) {
      // For now (up to Android 7.0) this is always available 
      bsd_signal_func = (bsd_signal_func_t) dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "bsd_signal");

      if (bsd_signal_func == NULL) {
        // You may try dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "signal") or dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "signal") here
        // Make sure you add a comment here in StackOverflow
        // if you find a device that doesn't have "bsd_signal" in its libc.so!!!

        __android_log_assert("", "bsd_signal_wrapper", "bsd_signal symbol not found!");
      }
    }

    return bsd_signal_func(s, f);
  }
}
#endif
```

PS. Looks like the `bsd_signal` symbol will be brought back to `libc.so` in **NDK r13**:

https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/160#issuecomment-236295994

Comment: also this headers may probably needed

#ifdef __ ANDROID __
#include <android/api-level.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#endif

Comment: @AntonPechenko Yeah, sure, let's have them in the code of my answer.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to try to load signal via dlsym when bsd_signal isn't found, since one of them is always available? I understand that bsd_signal has been found in device's libc.so up to Android 7.0, and that bsd_signal is coming back in r13, but due to the huge variety in Android devices this seems like a reasonable safeguard. Would there be any negative consequences?

Comment: I don't think the would be any negative consequences, I've put it as a suggestion in the code comment before and tbh I have it in my production code to be future-proof.The only thing I didn't like about it is that on the code I tested the "signal" taken with RTLD_DEFAULT had different address than the one taken from handle returned by dlopen("libc.so") on Android 6.0 and 7.0 devices. RTLD_NEXT had the same. So in my production code I take "signal" from RTLD_NEXT.

Comment: Of course i could've just use dlopen to be sure I get the right "signal" symbol, but I wanted my code as clean as possible without a need for a dlclose call somewhere when closing the app to decrease the reference counter. I'm not a POSIX/Linux expert though and I'm quite sure that killing the app will not make any leaks without dlclose. To sum up: it's just me being pedantic ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is ABI breakage in the Android NDK. Libraries/binaries built with a pre-android-21 NDK using signal() won't work with android-21 or newer. And the other way around. This Rust ticket has a more detailed explanation: https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/issues/236#issuecomment-198774409

There is also this ticket for the Android NDK: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/48