# Using openssl static library in android

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-ndk, openssl

I build openssl static library follow the openssl wiki,my build environment is as follows:

openssl-1.0.2h

ndk:android-ndk-r12b

android-api:android-14

android_arch=arch-arm

At first,I use md5 to test wether build success, it's ok.But when I use some other functions,there is a link error as follows:

```
libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function read_string_inner: error: undefined reference to 'bsd_signal'
```

I search this error and found that in android version less than or equal 19,in signal.h(https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/20ee6d20/ndk/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include/signal.h), there is bsd_signal symbol,but in android version 21 or higher signal.h, the bsd_signal was removed,so I changed android-api to 21 and rebuild the library,everything is ok on android version higher or equal 21, but on earlier version,it's failed.
I find the code in ui_openssl.c(https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/ui/ui_openssl.c)

Will this problem be solved if modify some source code?

I am very confuse about two point:

1. In every version in android ,there is a function called signal(),in
   previous version less than 21,it's a wrapper function of
   bsd_signal,in later version,It's not a wrapper function,so there
   must be no error when we called signal().
2. When I use android-api=14 to build library,the library have same
   error on android version less than 19 and higher than 19, in android
   version less than or equal 19 there is bsd_signed() in signal.h,I
   think the library must can be use in version less than 19 and can't
   use in other version.

Comment: I posted an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746904/android-linker-undefined-reference-to-bsd-signal/38660684#38660684